# How can this be done concurrently in scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

So I have this chunk of code

```
dbs.foreach({
  var map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, mutable.MutableList[String]]()
  db =>
    val resultList = getTables(hive, db)
    map+=(db -> resultList)
})
```

What this does is loops through a list of dbs, does a `show tables in db` call for each db, then adds the db -> table to a map.  How can this be done concurrently since there is about a 5 seconds wait time for the hive query to return?

update code --

```
def getAllTablesConcurrent(hive: JdbcHive, dbs: mutable.MutableList[String]): Map[String, mutable.MutableList[String]] = {
  implicit val context:ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
  val futures = dbs.map {
    db =>
        Future(db, getTables(hive, db))
    }
  val map = Await.result( Future.sequence(futures), Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ).toMap
  map
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the `var map = ...` be outside of the loop?

Comment: Please don't update your question with answer code. If you've found an answer sufficiently different from one already submitted then post it as an answer. You are permitted to answer your own question, even if you accept a different answer.

Comment: @jwvh it's not anwser code, it's sample code that another user was replying to.

Comment: It's not answer code? That's even worse! A week/month/year from now someone looking for help with their concurrency problem will come across this question and see the code, labeled only "update", notice it is very much like the accepted answer code and wonder, "How come this worked for @testacc but not for me?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want more control (how much time do you want to wait, how many threads do you want to use, what happens if all your threads are busy, etc) you can use ThreadPollExecutor and Future

```
  implicit val context:ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

  val dbs = List("db1", "db2", "db3")

  val futures = dbs.map {
   name => Future(name, getables(hive, name))
  }

  val result = Await.result( Future.sequence(futures), Duration(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) ).toMap
```

just remember not to create a new ExecutionContext every time you need it

Comment: Best way to "remember not to create a new ExecutionContext every time you need it" is to just `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` instead of creating one ;)

Comment: I am having one issue with this code chunk.  What ever is the last future to finish returns an empty value.  `getables(hive, name)` returns a List object of strings.  At random, whatever is the last future to finish, will have an empty list.  Is there any fix to this?  Edited my post with the exact code chunk I am using.

Comment: Does that happen randomly? How much time it takes to complete all the futures? (I saw you use 10 seconds)



It isn't related but remember not to create a new ExecutionContext every time you need it. Import `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` or create that val outside your method.

Comment: @SebastianCelestino It happens randomly, but always.  I made a very small test sample to use.  It has 3 objects it returns futures for, each takes 2~ seconds to complete(Just a sql call).  Whatever is the last object to return will just return empty no matter what.   I tried 20 futures, the same thing happened, the final future returned empty.  The program also does not end when all execution is compete, my very last line of code is a println("finished") and it will just hang there for 5 minutes.  Even if I set my timeout to `10 seconds` , I tried with a longer and shorter timeout, no change.

Comment: @testacc I couldn't reproduce the error, here is a gist with my code [https://gist.github.com/rkpost/3fddd93fafa2313c63c6d7a4b9cdea6b] 

The program doesn't finish because there are non daemon threads inside the ThreadPool. You can solve that in three different ways

1) Using `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`
2) Setting a custom ThreadFactory in order to crear daemon threads
3) Shuting down the Thread Pool

Comment: Thanks, getting page not found though

Comment: @testacc sorry, here is the right link
https://gist.github.com/rkpost/3fddd93fafa2313c63c6d7a4b9cdea6b

Answer (score 2):

Don't use vars and mutable state, *especially* if you want concurrency.

```
 val result: Future[Map[String, Seq[String]] = Future
   .traverse(dbs) { name => 
       Future(name -> getTables(hive, name) )
   }.map(_.toMap)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.par` on any Scala collection to perform the next transformation in parallel (using default parallelism which depends on number of cores).

Also - easier and cleaner to `map` into an (immutable) map instead of updating a mutable one.

```
val result = dbs.par.map(db => db -> getTables(hive, db)).toMap
```

To have more control on the number of concurrent threads used, see https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html